# JAX-RS API Leaking Threads

Tags: java, ajax, api, get

I have the following code:

```
public static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
        client.target("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").request().buildGet().submit(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {

            @Override
            public void completed(Response response) {
                response.close();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });

    }
    Thread.sleep(10000L);
    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
}
```

Each time I call .submit() the client creates a new thread for the new get request that just permanently stays open. The problem with this is that I eventually reach the max # of threads and the program malfunctions because it cannot create a new thread. How do I avoid this problem?

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
...
101
```

The ideal solution would be to make this program single threaded and hang the program until each get-request receives a response. I'm open to using an alternative API if this is not possible with javax.ws.rs.

Comment: Interesting. Which JAX-RS implementation are you using? For a start, can you set a fixed-size thread pool to the client - `client = ClientBuilder.executorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)).build();` and see how it behaves?

Comment: Here's my gradle dependencies:
    implementation group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0'
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-client', version: '4.7.2.Final'

Looks like a very old version of JAX-RS, that might have something to do with it.